# Unity ReadPixels return black screen in samsung note

Tags: screenshot, unity-game-engine, samsung-mobile

I have the code:

```
savedImage = new Texture2D((int) this.camera.pixelWidth, (int) this.camera.pixelHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
savedImage.ReadPixels(this.camera.pixelRect, 0, 0);
savedImage.Apply ();
```

It just somehow takes a screenshot.
This code works well on Samsung SI and SIII but not on Note. On Samsung Note, it only returns a black screen.  Does anyone have an idea why it is like this? Thank you very much?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.